# Запятые и скобки

Tags: запятые

Вера предполагает свободный, (даже если не всегда сознательный), выбор и не может проистекать из принуждения.
Надо ли выделять скобки запятыми?

Comment: Это перевод, такие правки "невозможны".

Comment: "Даже если не всегда" - это явное условие, которое используется с глаголами. Здесь условие не нужно и плохо подходит. Лучше заменить на "пусть и не всегда" или "хоть и не всегда". Или на "даже если неосознанный".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скобки заменяют запятые. То есть без скобок нужно было бы использовать запятые. Но отделять скобки запятыми нельзя.

В скобках пишется дополнительная информация, которая указывается после слова/фразы.

Корректный вариант:

*Вера предполагает свободный выбор (даже если не всегда сознательный) и не может проистекать из принуждения.*